# Simultaneous equation help appreciated

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this simultaneous equation? I know it has multiple solutions, but would anyone be able to show me the exact steps in working these out for future reference?

$$
\begin{cases}
2x +y = 4\\
-6x - 3y = -12
\end{cases}
$$

Thank you...

Comment: Basically, you want to get two of the variables to have the same number in front of them by multiplying or dividing the _whole_ equation by any number that will make it the same as any of the other equations as explained above. Then you want to subtract(or add) the two equations from each other to eliminate the variable you have chosen. You will just repeat this as well as use substitution to eventually find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As $2x+y=4-6x-3y=-12$

So, $2x+y=-12,y=-12-2x$

Putting $y=-12-2x$ in $4-6x-3y=-12$

$4-6x-3\{-12-2x\}=-12$

or $52=12$ which is impossible

So, the simultaneous equation will not have any solution

**EDIT** :
Due to the change in the question to $2x+y=4,-6x-3y=-12$

Again, from the 1st equation, $y=-12-2x$

Putting $y=-12-2x$ in $-6x-3y=-12$ we get, $12=12$ which is true for all values of $y$

So, $(x,-12-2x)$ will satisfy the given  simultaneous equation for all values of $x$

Comment: I think your solution is for a different system, perhaps prior to the edit. You  have not used equations $2x+y=4$ and $−6x−3y=−12$, as they are now.

Comment: @AméricoTavares, ya. Please find the original version.

Comment: It is "2x + y = 4 -6x - 3y = -12".

Comment: @AméricoTavares, Earlier I solved for that. Now edited the answer as the question is changed

Comment: Typo in "(...) from the 1st equation, $y=−12−2x$". Should be $y=4−2x$.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $2x+y=4$ and $-6x-3y=-12$

Let's begin by solving each equation for $y$ and labelling them:

$\Rightarrow y=4-2x \hspace{80 mm}$ (i)

$\Rightarrow y=\dfrac{12-6x}{3}=4-2x \hspace{58.5 mm}$ (ii)

Graphically, these two lines overlap.

Therefore, the system of equations has an infinite number of solutions.